# Type Error while executing a job using Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-circuit, programming

I am using this circuit and trying to execute it
[image: circuit]

It is created using the function

```
def apply_fixed_ansatz(qubits, parameters):

    for iz in range (0, len(qubits)):
        circ.ry(parameters[0][iz], qubits[iz])

    circ.cz(qubits[0], qubits[1])
    circ.cz(qubits[2], qubits[0])

    for iz in range (0, len(qubits)):
        circ.ry(parameters[1][iz], qubits[iz])

    circ.cz(qubits[1], qubits[2])
    circ.cz(qubits[2], qubits[0])

    for iz in range (0, len(qubits)):
        circ.ry(parameters[2][iz], qubits[iz])
```

I added parameters to it using the line

```
apply_fixed_ansatz([0, 1, 2], [[3.60955579, 1.06944298, 1.6183139], [-1.19248748, 0.11895816, 2.13073899], [-0.32517705, 2.45498693, 2.13752322]])
```

When I try to run the code

```
backend = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
t_circ = transpile(circ, backend)
qobj = assemble(t_circ)
job = backend.run(qobj)

result = job.result()
o = result.get_statevector(circ, decimals=10)
print(o)
```

It throws an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Cell In[21], line 4
    job = backend.run(qobj)
  File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit_aer/backends/aerbackend.py:196 in run
    return self._run_qobj(circuits, validate, parameter_binds, **run_options)
TypeError: AerBackend._run_qobj() got multiple values for argument 'parameter_binds'
```

Did I wrongly assign the parameters? How do I fix this?
This code is from [Qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-paper-implementations/vqls.html#2.-The-Algorithm)

Comment: `backend.run(qobj)` works in my machine. What's your Qiskit version?

Comment: @Egretta.Thula sorry for replying quite late. My Qiskit version is 0.42.0. I managed to run this using ```backend = Aer.get_backend("aer_simulator")``` then ```result = execute(circ, backend = backend).result()```. Although i wonder if both are same?? I guess for proper efficiency I need transpile and assemble.